# How to emulate outdated SSL Provider on Android?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm implementing 'Update security provider' feature for an Android application.
I implemented as it said in 'Patch asynchronously' and need to test/emulate all outcomes: user prompt demonstration and the error is unrecoverable.

I tried to delete Play Store updates, use previous com.google.gms:google-services version or android 6.0 — it always silently goes to `onProviderInstalled()`, never shows prompt or goes to `onProviderInstallFailed()`.

I did exactly as said at https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider#example_async

Also in `android\build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3")
    }
}
```